# Segmentation-fault with PyObject_Call() in shared library for iTunes

Tags: python, windows, plugins, segmentation-fault, cython

I'm experimenting with the iTunes SDK and Cython. The DLL entry-point seems to work, but using any *"real Python"* causes iTunes to crash.

The following code compiles fine and the plugin-dll is loaded successfully by iTunes.

```
cimport libc.stdio      as stdio

cdef extern from "iTunesAPI/iTunesAPI.h":

    ctypedef int    OSType
    ctypedef int    OSStatus

    ctypedef struct PluginMessageInfo:
        pass

    int             unimpErr

cdef public OSStatus iTunesPluginMain( OSType               message,
                                       PluginMessageInfo*   messageInfo,
                                       void*                refCon ):
    cdef stdio.FILE*    fl = stdio.fopen('C:/itunes_cyplugin_feedback.txt', 'wb')
    return unimpErr
```

But adding a Python-expression will cause iTunes to crash, e.g:

```
# ...

cdef public OSStatus iTunesPluginMain( OSType               message,
                                       PluginMessageInfo*   messageInfo,
                                       void*                refCon ):
    object()
    return unimpErr
```

**Do you have an idea of why this causes a crash?**

*OS*: Windows 7 x64
*iTunes*: 10.5 x86
*Compiler*: gcc 4.6.2 (MinGW)

---

*Edit [2012/02/12]*

New insights gave me the *gdb* session, which you can find below. I hope someone can now tell me how to fix it. :)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes>gdb iTunes.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b write
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (write) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program: c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.exe
[New Thread 4588.0xa20]
[New Thread 4588.0x1214]
[New Thread 4588.0x12f4]
[New Thread 4588.0x274]
[New Thread 4588.0x1070]
[New Thread 4588.0xf40]
[New Thread 4588.0xfb0]
[New Thread 4588.0x12b0]
[New Thread 4588.0xb48]
[New Thread 4588.0x58c]
[New Thread 4588.0xc7c]
[New Thread 4588.0x1048]
[New Thread 4588.0x8ac]
[New Thread 4588.0x10dc]
[New Thread 4588.0x190]
[New Thread 4588.0x128]
[New Thread 4588.0xfbc]
[New Thread 4588.0xc2c]
[New Thread 4588.0x1154]
[New Thread 4588.0x234]
[New Thread 4588.0xa70]
[New Thread 4588.0x1144]
[New Thread 4588.0xa48]
[New Thread 4588.0xbe8]
warning: ASL checking for logging parameters in environment variable "iTunes.exe.log"

warning: ASL checking for logging parameters in environment variable "asl.log"

BFD: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WMVCORE.DLL: Warning: Ignoring section flag IMAGE_SCN_MEM_NOT_PAGED in section .reloc

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x1e0650bc in python27!PyObject_Call () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll
(gdb)
(gdb) bt all
No symbol "all" in current context.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x1e0650bc in python27!PyObject_Call () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll
#1  0x02eb12ae in iTunesPluginMain (__pyx_v_message=1768843636, __pyx_v_messageInfo=0x16e6b0, __pyx_v_refCon=0x0)
    at pytunes.c:465
#2  0x68a4d627 in iTunes!getPhaseStreamLibraryVersion () from c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.dll
#3  0x696e6974 in iTunesMainEntryPoint@24 () from c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.dll
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

And this is what Visual Studio 2008 tells me:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x1e0650bc in iTunes.exe: 0xC0000005
Segmentation fault when reading at 0x00000004.
```

---

*Edit [2012/02/13]*

The following is the output of `(gdb) thread apply all bt` after iTunes crashed.

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 24 (thread 4340.0x4e0):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x0000067c in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 23 (thread 4340.0x17a0):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76178f8f in UnregisterPowerSettingNotification () from C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll
#2  0x59bd3485 in iTunesMobileDevice!AFCConnectionGetStatus ()
   from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\iTunesMobileDevice.dll
#3  0x06fef87c in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 22 (thread 4340.0x10c4):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e7c in ntdll!ZwYieldExecution () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e4067b in ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerShiftLeft () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 21 (thread 4340.0x14ec):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x0000063c in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x06edf8c0 in ?? ()
#6  0x73ae556e in CreatePropertySheetPageA ()
   from C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\co
mctl32.dll
#7  0x7650f003 in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x765d6172 in ole32!CoRevokeClassObject () from C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
#9  0x765dc80b in ole32!CoIsOle1Class () from C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
#10 0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#11 0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#12 0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#13 0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 20 (thread 4340.0x1628):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000650 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 19 (thread 4340.0xf04):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x000005c0 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 18 (thread 4340.0x3c4):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75046872 in KERNELBASE!GetProcessId () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#4  0x068af914 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 17 (thread 4340.0x880):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75046872 in KERNELBASE!GetProcessId () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#4  0x0665f758 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 16 (thread 4340.0x165c):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75046872 in KERNELBASE!GetProcessId () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#4  0x05e2f5a8 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 14 (thread 4340.0xb6c):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000580 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x063cfe08 in ?? ()
#6  0x737f53a6 in ?? ()
#7  0x5cea92e4 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000580 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000001e in ?? ()
#10 0x00000024 in ?? ()
#11 0x00000001 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 13 (thread 4340.0xc74):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000548 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 12 (thread 4340.0x778):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e7c in ntdll!ZwYieldExecution () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e4067b in ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerShiftLeft () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 10 (thread 4340.0x1620):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e54c1c in ntdll!ZwDeleteValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75041876 in SleepEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 9 (thread 4340.0x10cc):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e7c in ntdll!ZwYieldExecution () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e4067b in ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerShiftLeft () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 8 (thread 4340.0xac4):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e7c in ntdll!ZwYieldExecution () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e4067b in ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerShiftLeft () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 7 (thread 4340.0xe08):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75046872 in KERNELBASE!GetProcessId () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#4  0x057df9f0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 6 (thread 4340.0x7fc):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e7c in ntdll!ZwYieldExecution () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e4067b in ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerShiftLeft () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 5 (thread 4340.0x61c):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x76e3ef27 in ntdll!RtlIsValidIndexHandle () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x76511174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x76e6b3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x76e6b3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 4 (thread 4340.0x1794):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e4c in ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x75046872 in KERNELBASE!GetProcessId () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000002 in ?? ()
#4  0x04e8f9e8 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (thread 4340.0x51c):
#0  0x76e564f4 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76e55e6c in ntdll!ZwWriteVirtualMemory () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7504179c in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00000218 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (thread 4340.0x17b4):
#0  0x1e0650bc in python27!PyObject_Call () from C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
#1  0x69781232 in iTunesPluginMain (__pyx_v_message=1768843636, __pyx_v_msgInfo=0x13e680, __pyx_v_refCon=0x0)
    at pytunes.c:467
#2  0x5bc1d217 in iTunes!getPhaseStreamLibraryVersion () from C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.dll
#3  0x696e6974 in ?? ()
#4  0x0013e680 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

---

*Edit [2012/02/13]*

I just got the idea *Why not try it in C?*, and so I did. And it doesn't work either, iTunes still crashes. Maybe I should rename the question to "How to embed Python into iTunes?" ..

*EDIT*: The pure C implementation now does not cause iTunes to crash, but I dunno what I did wrong last time.

```
#include "iTunesAPI/iTunesAPI.h"
#include <Python.h>

__declspec(dllexport) OSStatus iTunesPluginMain(OSType              message,
                                                PluginMessageInfo*  msgInfo,
                                                void*               refCon) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* op = Py_BuildValue("i", 123);
    Py_Finalize();
    return unimpErr;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the gdb backtrace? to see if it's a issue when the gil is released or something

Comment: @tito Hm, how can I debug a *.dll* with `gdb`? Can't find a way to do so.. :/ `(gdb) file pytunes.dll \\ (gdb) run ../itunes.exe` does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: I've absolutely no idea on windows. But if you can get a backtrace, then it will be easier to found what's wrong.

Comment: @tito I've added what gdb tells me, I hope this will help. :)

Comment: Well, no, you must show the backtrace, and since you have threads too, you can type: "bt all".

Comment: @tito Oh ok. Well my first time I am debugging with gdb. I'll add that tomorrow. Ty

Comment: @tito I've added the backtrace at the end of the gdb session.

Comment: mmh, ok, i was thinking to got the backtrace of "all threads with bt all, but no" :/ Try to put ``with gil:`` and inside the block put the ``<tab>object()``. If you still have a segfault, use "thread apply all bt" to show it. What i'm searching for is if another thread are already executing some python or something like that.

Comment: Also, i think on windows, you might need to declare your plugin function in a certain manner no ? like "__declspec(dllexport)" in front of it. I'll search how to do it with cython

Comment: Look like the definition must be ``cdef api ...`` instead of ``cdef``, according to http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `api` keyword. 1) `with gil:` gives me *Trying to acquire the GIL while it is already held*. Using `with nogil:` doesn't work either, *Constructing Python tuple not allowed without gil*. 2) Using `cdef public api` results in the same error, backtraces are equal. Using only `cdef api` does not export the function to be available for the dll-clients. See the edit for the output of `thread apply all bt`. Thank you very much for your investments of your time and help so far!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7622/discussion-between-tito-and-niklas-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the backtrace, i don't see any other python call. And then an idea came in my head: since you are trying to do a itunes plugin (C) with Cython (Python), the Python interpreter might not be initialized. You need to create an intermediate C file for bootstraping the python interpreter and initialize the cython module before actually using it:

In the main.c:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "../iTunesAPI/iTunesAPI.h"
#include "pytunes.c"

__declspec(dllexport) OSStatus iTunesPluginMain( OSType             message,
                                                 PluginMessageInfo* msgInfo,
                                                 void*              refCon ) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    initpytunes();
    return PyTunes_main(message, msgInfo, refCon);
}
```

And in your pytunes.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "../iTunesAPI/iTunesAPI.h":

    ctypedef int        OSType
    ctypedef int        OSStatus

    ctypedef struct PluginMessageInfo:
        pass

    int unimpErr

cdef public int PyTunes_main(   OSType               message,
                                PluginMessageInfo*   msgInfo,
                                void*                refCon ):
    object()
    return 0
```

Now the python interpreter will be safely initialized, and cython extension too, before calling the cython/c function :)

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately not the solution. Calling `Py_Initialize` outside of `with gil:` gives me an error in Cython: *Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil*, putting it in the scope of `with gil:` compiling with Cython works, but iTunes still crashes. Just as I wanted to post my try to do the whole thing in *C* only, I saw your answer. Please take a look at the edited question. Ty

Comment: Just declare the Py_Initialize with nogil too.

Comment: Ahh right, that fixes the Cython compilation error. But still not the iTunes crash.. :/

Comment: Can you share the generated .c on paste.pocoo.org ?

Comment: Yes, the same crash. [The generated code](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/550262/) [(cython-code)](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/550263/) is about 1000 lines, have you seen my latest edit on the question? It's the bare C-implementation which is not working, either.

Comment: *Ah*, not exactly the same. Still Segmantation fault, but: `0x1e0d4533 in python27!PyInterpreterState_Delete () from C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll`

Comment: *I am* confused, I could swear the pure C code didn't work, just tried it again and it does..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7626/discussion-between-tito-and-niklas-r)

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially in the chat. You made my day. Definitely the bounty worth. ;-)