# Py_InitModule4() returns NULL on embedded Python-interpreter (with Cython)

Tags: python, c, embed, cython

I'm writing a C-Plugin using Cython. In final, this should embed the Python-Interpreter into iTunes on Windows. In order for this to work, a [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114214/segmentation-fault-with-pyobject-call-in-shared-library-for-itunes) is needed. It implements the iTunes plugin entry-point, initializes or finalizes, or whatever is needed, to then call code generated from Cython.

I'm using *MinGW gcc 4.6.2* on *Windows 7 64Bit* and *CPython 2.7*.

**Preamble**

The iTunes plugin entry-point on Windows is called `iTunesPluginMain`. As far as I understood it, the shared library that implements the plugin is *not* kept all the time iTunes is running and therefore you can *not* store any global-variables once the entry-point was called. That's why iTunes want's the developer to store a `void*` pointer to a handle that is passed every call to `iTunesPluginMain`.

`iTunesPluginMain` is called for several notifications, such as initialization and cleanup.

The bootstrapper looks like this:

```
/** coding: utf-8
    file:   bootstrap.c
    Copyright (c) 2012 by Niklas Rosenstein

    This file implements the bootstrapper for loading the PyTunes plugin. **/

#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iTunesVisualAPI/iTunesAPI.h>

#include "pytunes.c"

#define EXPORT(type) __declspec(dllexport) type

extern void     initpytunes(void);
extern OSStatus PyTunes_Main(OSType, PluginMessageInfo*, void*);

EXPORT(OSStatus) iTunesPluginMain(OSType message, PluginMessageInfo* msgInfo, void* refCon) {

    OSStatus status             = unimpErr;
    char     handlePyMain       = 1;

    switch(message) {
        case kPluginInitMessage: {
            // Sent to notify the plugin that this is the first time it is loaded
            // and should register itself to iTunes

            char** argv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1);
            argv[0]     = malloc(sizeof(char)  * 256);

            // WinAPI call, retrieves the path to iTunes.exe
            GetModuleFileName(0, argv[0], 256);

            // Initialize the Python-interpreter
            Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
            PyEval_InitThreads();
            Py_Initialize();
            PySys_SetArgvEx(1, argv, 0);
            handlePyMain = 1;

            free(argv[0]);
            free(argv);
            break;
        }

        case kPluginCleanupMessage: {
            // Sent to cleanup the memory when the plugin gets unload

            status       = PyTunes_Main(message, msgInfo, refCon);
            handlePyMain = 0;
            Py_Finalize();
            break;
        }

        default: break;
    }

    if (handlePyMain != 0) {
        initpytunes();
        status = PyTunes_Main(message, msgInfo, refCon);
    }

    return status;
}
```

`pytunes.c` is generated by *Cython*. Now what the bootstrapper does, or should do, is the following:

1. Identify what iTunes wants to tell the plugin

   - If iTunes notifies it about the initialization, it retrieves the path to `iTunes.exe` through a Windows API call and initializes the Python interpreter.
   - If iTunes notifies it to cleanup (e.g. iTunes closes), it finalizes the Python interpreter. Note that the "Cython-call" is done before this happens and `handlePyMain` is set to zero so it isn't executed again when the interpreter is already finalized.
2. If `handlePyMain` is not set to zero, which indicates the Cython-call should not be executed, `initpytunes` and `PyTunes_Main`, which are generated from Cython, are called. The call to `initpytunes` is necessary as Cython does initializations to global variables there. `PyTunes_Main` is finally the Cython implementation of what the plugin does.

**The Cython Implementation**

The call to `PyTunes_Main`, which is implemented in `pytunes.pyx`, runs smooth. The following implementation opens a file at my desktop and writes a message into it.

```
cimport iTunesVisualAPI     as itapi

cdef public itapi.OSStatus PyTunes_Main(itapi.OSType message,
                                        itapi.PluginMessageInfo* msgInfo,
                                        void* refCon):
    fl = open("C:/Users/niklas/Desktop/feedback.txt", "w")
    print >> fl, "Greetings from PyTunes!"
    fl.close()
    return itapi.unimpErr
```

When i start iTunes, the file is created and the text is written into it.

`iTunesVisalAPI.pxd` contains the `cdef extern from "iTunesVisualAPI/iTunesVisualAPI.h"` declarations to make the API available for Cython, but that is of lesser importance here.

**Problem description**

The problem occurs, just for example, when importing the `sys` module in Cython *and* using it. Simple example:

```
cimport iTunesVisualAPI     as itapi

import sys

cdef public itapi.OSStatus PyTunes_Main(itapi.OSType message,
                                        itapi.PluginMessageInfo* msgInfo,
                                        void* refCon):
    fl = open("C:/Users/niklas/Desktop/feedback.txt", "w")
    print >> fl, sys
    fl.close()
    return itapi.unimpErr
```

This causes iTunes to crash. This is the full *gdb-session*, which will tell us what the problem actually is.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes>gdb -q iTunes.exe
Reading symbols from c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b pytunes.c:553
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (pytunes.c:553) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program: c:\program files (x86)\itunes\iTunes.exe
[New Thread 3244.0x3a8]
[New Thread 3244.0xd90]
[New Thread 3244.0x11c0]
[New Thread 3244.0x125c]
[New Thread 3244.0x1354]
[New Thread 3244.0x690]
[New Thread 3244.0x3d8]
[New Thread 3244.0xdb8]
[New Thread 3244.0xe74]
[New Thread 3244.0xf2c]
[New Thread 3244.0x13c0]
[New Thread 3244.0x1038]
[New Thread 3244.0x12b4]
[New Thread 3244.0x101c]
[New Thread 3244.0x10b0]
[New Thread 3244.0x140]
[New Thread 3244.0x10e4]
[New Thread 3244.0x848]
[New Thread 3244.0x1b0]
[New Thread 3244.0xc84]
[New Thread 3244.0xd5c]
[New Thread 3244.0x12dc]
[New Thread 3244.0x12fc]
[New Thread 3244.0xf84]
warning: ASL checking for logging parameters in environment variable "iTunes.exe.log"

warning: ASL checking for logging parameters in environment variable "asl.log"

BFD: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WMVCORE.DLL: Warning: Ignoring section flag IMAGE_SCN_MEM_NOT_PAGED in section .reloc

Breakpoint 1, PyTunes_Main (__pyx_v_message=1768843636, __pyx_v_msgInfo=0xd7e798, __pyx_v_refCon=0x0)
    at C:/Users/niklas/Desktop/pytunes/pytunes/build-cython/pytunes.c:553
553       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetName(__pyx_m, __pyx_n_s__sys); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno
 = 75; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
(gdb) print __pyx_m
$1 = (PyObject *) 0x0
(gdb) print __pyx_n_s__sys
$2 = (PyObject *) 0x92f42c0
(gdb) print __pyx_t_1
$3 = (PyObject *) 0x0
(gdb) step
__Pyx_GetName (dict=0x0, name=0x92f42c0) at C:/Users/niklas/Desktop/pytunes/pytunes/build-cython/pytunes.c:788
788         result = PyObject_GetAttr(dict, name);
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x1e089f57 in python27!PyObject_GetAttr () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll
(gdb)
```

*Sidenote: Line 553 is the line where the Python statement `print >> fl, sys` was handled by Cython. You can find the full generated source-code of `pytunes.c` on [paste.pocoo.org](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/552233/).*

The debug-session tells us that `__pyx_m_t` is used in context with using the `sys` module in the Cython code (why ever?). Anyway, it is a *NULL*-pointer. It should be initialized on line *699*. `Py_InitModule4` obviously returns *NULL* and therefore an *ImportError* should be raised within `initpytunes`. (You can find the corresponding implementation of `goto __pyx_L1_error` at line *751*).

To check this, I've modified the code a bit, and the result is "positive" in that context.

```
    if (handlePyMain != 0) {
        initpytunes();
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyObject* exception, *value, *traceback;
            PyErr_Fetch(&exception, &value, &traceback);
            PyObject* errString = PyObject_Str(exception);

            // WinAPI call
            MessageBox(NULL, PyString_AsString(errString), "PyErr_Occurred()?", 0);
            status = paramErr;
        }
        else {
            // WinAPI call
            MessageBox(NULL, "No error, calling PyTunes_Main.", "PyPyErr_Occurred()?", 0);
            status = PyTunes_Main(message, msgInfo, refCon);
        }
    }
```

[image: message-box displaying the name of the exception]

**The Question**

Do you know or have an idea what I am doing wrong? Maybe I initialize the Python-interpreter wrong? The most bizarre part is, I had a working prototype of this. But I can't get it to work anymore! (see below)

*References and Notes*

You may want to see the full source. You can find the *working* prototype [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?avmrw5mnz7yvib5) ([Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/file/d22df715ace2aa0d3451465b4b374ed96aee1d23ac60e0026acf86eb1827f3e1/analysis/1329426823/)) and the actual project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?hxt4rd9me5axtpg) ([Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/file/36cdbdf3192f9db7e247588127418ff6ed0cc6bdc11239bf379c716317421f87/analysis/1329426735/)). (Both, links to mediafire.com)

As I am not allowed to distribute the iTunesVisualSDK with it, [here](https://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunesvisualsdk.html) is a link to download it from apple.com.

Please do not comment "Why not work with the prototype?" or alike. It is a *prototype* and I write prototypes dirty and unclean, and usually I achieve better results when rewriting the whole thing.

---

Thanks for anyone looking at this, reading it carefully and investing time into helping me to solve my problem. :-)
-Niklas

Comment: Add the value of the exception to the msgbox. That may give you a clue. Maybe it can't find the stdlib. The value will tell you which module it couldn't import.

Comment: Also, I know you didn't get to that point yet but Python uses global state so you might (will) get into trouble if iTunes decides to unload your dll between calls to main.

Comment: @yak Oh My God! That is so embrassing! I was so convinced the creation of the `pytunes` module failed, I didn't look at the value of the exception. `No module named iTunesVis`, shame on me. `cimport iTunesVis as it` is one of the lines of `pytunes.pxd`. And as there is a Python-class declaration in `iTunesVis.pxd`, Cython expects a module called *iTunesVis*. Removing the Python-declarations or removing that *cimport* at all fixes it. Thank you very much, I really should've done this before asking the question.. >.> Maybe you want to write an answer? Free reputation lol.

Comment: @yak Hm, I dind't think about that actually.. Would that mean I'd need to Initialize *and* Finalize the interpreter on *every* call to `iTunesPluginMain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ImportError` indicates that Python could not import a module. Check the value of the exception to see which module wasn't found.

Module `init` functions return `void` so you should always call `PyErr_Occurred()` after it to check if it failed. If an error occurred, you have to handle it, preferably by showing it to the user in some way. If stdout is available, `PyErr_Print()` will print out a complete traceback.

I'm not sure how iTunes plugins work but if it indeed unloads DLLs between calls then Python will be unloaded as well and its state will be lost. You would need to call `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` in every call to `iTunesPluginMain()` which means that all your Python objects would be lost as well. Most likely not what you want.

One idea to prevent that could be to re-open your plugin DLL in `kPluginInitMessage` and close it in `kPluginCleanupMessage`. Windows keeps track of how many times a DLL has been opened by a process. A DLL is unloaded only after the count reaches 0. So if you call `LoadLibrary()` in your DLL, the count will increase to 2 and the DLL will be unloaded only after both iTunes and your code call `FreeLibrary()`.

Note that this is just an (untested) idea.

Comment: Thank you very much yak! And yes, I have exactly come to that problem now. I can not start a thread in Python because after `iTunesPluginMain` ended, everything from Python is gone. Your idea is evident and is very appreciated. I'm gonna try that, thank you!

Comment: Do I have to do any special initialization-stuff in order to make threading in Python work? I've called `LoadLibrary` but that did not fix it, threads are still killed when `iTunesPluginMain` ended. I guess, best would be to open another question on this?

Comment: Hm wait, there must be something wrong. I can't delete the `pytunes.dll` now while iTunes is opened, so it isn't unloaded. It must be something else.

Comment: Knowing Apple they probably went extra lengths to ensure "proper" plugins behavior. Maybe you could use multiple processes?

Comment: What do you mean with *went extra lengths to ensure "proper" plugins behavior*? | I've never worked with multi-processing, neither in Python nor in C. Any references on how to achieve what you think of?