# C# - iTunes Bootstrap

Tags: c#, api, com, itunes

I'm making an DLL that listens to iTunes events through the COM Api, but I was wondering how to make this DLL be loaded when iTunes is started, like Windows Media Player does with it's plugins.

I've tried to add `ComVisible(true)` to the main app class, to see if iTunes detects it and initializes it via the `ctor`, with no results.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know where to start. I've tried to create iTunesPluginMain as cited here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319315/py-initmodule4-returns-null-on-embedded-python-interpreter-with-cython but still nothing.

Comment: You could always just write a hidden console app that launches DLL when iTunes launches. Then just set that console app to run at startup.

Comment: The DLL is supposed to write a log in my desktop when initilized. But since the log doesn't exists, I guess the dll isn't being loaded by iTunes.

Comment: Tried with this code: http://pastebin.com/eKpHtCZE

Comment: A log does not determine whether a DLL is loaded or not...

Comment: Also, combining "Desktop" with "log" results in ".../Desktop/log", not ".../Desktop/log.txt", which you may want.

Comment: Since there's no folder called log at my desktop, the file must be written. Anyway, changing from "log" to "log.txt" still does not has created the file, which indicates that iTunes has not loaded the plugin.